# Can I redefine a method / constructor using reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode

I have a class called `A` and I need to create a new object of that class without calling its constructor. I want to set all its attributes through reflection.

Can I redefine the constructor of class `A` using reflection?

Or is there any way other way to do this?

Comment: sounds like you are unhappy with a third party library and you want to make some changes to a particular class. when i encounter such scenarios, i would define my class with the same package and class name as the third library. then i make sure that my "enhanced" class takes precedence over the third library's class during classloading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Sun/Oracle JVm you can use `Unsafe.allocateInstance(Class)`.  Otherwise you have to generate byte code to create the instance without calling a constructor. You could use ASM for this. You cannot create an instance without a constructor using Reflection alone.

BTW: You can define a new method using byte code manipulation, but to add a constructor, you have to change the class before it is loaded. (This is tricky to do)

Comment: This is really interesting, it wud be great if u cud shed a little more light on "change the class before its loaded".... Ur solution almost solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Nik, Unless you almost know how to do this there is no way, I could describe what you need to do in a few words. The simplest approach would be to use a Java agent to Instrument the class byte code before it is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Invoke the object with the constructor that takes the least amount of arguments; using dummy arguments.  Then proceed to manipulate the object however you like.

Comment: That could have side-effects if that particular constructor does anything (e.g. allocate resources, etc.)